# Is there any easier way to edit git notes?

Tags: git

Is there any other way to edit git notes, like setting default editor etc, rather than `git notes --ref=$ABC edit $COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git notes since 1.7.1 http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-notes-and-core-editor-config-td5910253.html obeys your editor settings.

Edit: if you *really* want to, you can study http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-git-notes.html and

```
git checkout notes/commits
[point editor at the commit hash you want to]
git commit -am 'whatever'
git update-ref refs/notes/commits 1234567
```

Where 1234567 is the [the hash that the commit reported]. Ugh. But doable.